# Functorial description of $\mathrm{Bl}_p\mathbb{P}^n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is an Exercise 0.3.13 (p.22) of [Alper](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ejarod/moduli.pdf). Consider $\mathbb{P}^n=\mathrm{Proj}\big(\mathbb{Z}[x_0,\cdots,x_n]\big)$ and $\{p\}=\mathbb{V}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$.

Let $A$ be a ring (commutative unital). I expect that a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to \mathrm{Bl}_p\mathbb{P}^n$ is equivalent to the data $(f,L,d,M,g)$, where:

- $L$ is an invertible $A$-module and $f:\bigoplus_{i=0}^nA\twoheadrightarrow L$ is a surjective $A$-linear map;
- $d\in\mathbb{N}_+$;
- $M$ is an invertible $A$-module and a surjective $A$-linear map
  $$g:\bigoplus_{m=0}^\infty(I_{1,\cdots,n})^{md}\twoheadrightarrow\mathrm{Sym}_A^\bullet M$$
  for $I_{1,\cdots,n}:=f\Big(\bigoplus_{i=1}^nA\Big)\cdot L^{-1}\subseteq A$. Note that the direct sum is over $i=1,\cdots,n$ and $i=0$ is excluded.

Two data $(f,L,d,M,g)$ and $(f',L',d',M',g')$ are equivalent if

- there is an isomorphism $\phi:L\cong L'$ such that $f'=\phi\circ f$, which implies $I_{1,\cdots,n}=I'_{1,\cdots,n}$, denoted by $I$ for simplicity;
- there is a common multiple $d''\in\mathbb{N}_+$ of $d,d'$ and an isomorphism $\psi:\mathrm{Sym}^{d''/d}M\cong \mathrm{Sym}^{d''/d'}M'$ such that $g'_{d''/d'}=\psi\circ g_{d''/d}$.

In other words, we shall have a functorial bijection for rings $A$
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Sch}}(\mathrm{Spec}(A),\mathrm{Bl}_p\mathbb{P}^n)\cong \{(f,L,d,M,g)\textrm{ as above}\}/\sim. $$

Comment: I'm not sure if you've already checked this, but if not, Hartshorne's proposition II.7.14 would be a good place to start.